# How can I get Oracle to have a better execution plan for this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

We have some tables which keep track of processed transactions. These tables have millions of rows. Often times I want to look at the most recent X transactions, so I have a query like this to pull the info I want from a few tables:

```
select a.id, b.field_one, c.field_two
from trans a, table_two b, table_three c
where a.id = b.id
and a.id = c.id
and a.id in
  (select id from trans where id > (select max(id) from trans) - 100);
```

Right now the query is very slow. The explain plan shows a full table scan on B and C. Now, if I evaluate the nested query separately and replace it with a list of comma separated IDs, the query is very fast. This seems obvious to me - it will only have 100 rows to join together so of course it will be faster than if it answered the query by first joining A and B together.

Conceptually I understand the query optimizer is trying to find a good execution plan but in this case it seems like it is doing a terrible job. Is there any way to force the DBMS to execute the nested query first? Possibly by using a Hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is probably obsuring the fact that only a maximum of 100 rows are being selected from trans.

Try this:

```
with cte_last_trans as (
  select id
  from   (select   id
          from     trans
          where    id > (select max(id)-100 from trans)
          order by id desc)
  where  rownum <= 100)
select a.id,
       b.field_one,
       c.field_two
from   cte_last_trans a,
       table_two      b,
       table_three    c
where  a.id = b.id
and    a.id = c.id
```

By the way, have you thought of the possibility that not all values of id might be present? If you want 100 rows to be returned, use:

```
with cte_last_trans as (
  select id
  from   (select   id
          from     trans
          order by id desc)
  where  rownum <= 100)
select a.id,
       b.field_one,
       c.field_two
from   cte_last_trans a,
       table_two      b,
       table_three    c
where  a.id = b.id
and    a.id = c.id
```

Comment: I got this approach working - the query executes very quickly. I think the key is rownum <= 100. I tried a few other things too (hints) but this is the only way that really speeds up the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a NO_MERGE hint which will force Oracle to execute the inner query first and not try to merge the two queries.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT /*+NO_MERGE(seattle_dept)*/ e1.last_name, seattle_dept.department_name 
  FROM employees e1, 
    (SELECT location_id, department_id, department_name 
       FROM departments 
      WHERE location_id = 1700) seattle_dept 
  WHERE e1.department_id = seattle_dept.department_id;



select /*+ no_merge(inner) */ a.id, b.field_one, c.field_two
  from trans a, 
       table_two b, 
       table_three c, 
       (select id from trans where id > (select max(id) from trans) - 100) inner
 where a.id = b.id
   and a.id = c.id
   and a.id = inner.id;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not sure the no_merge hint works with in clauses.  YOu may have to re-write the query to use a inline query.

Comment: You can disable [subquery unnesting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_transform.htm#BABEIDIA) with the `NO_UNNEST` hint.

Comment: Tossing a +1 here because this is the answer I was looking for.. But even with the hint it was still doing a FTS, so it appears the hint didn't really change anything.

Comment: You may need to force an index scan on the inner query with a hint on the nested select.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select a.id, b.field_one, c.field_two
 from trans a, table_two b, table_three c
 where a.id = b.id
 and a.id = c.id
 and a.id between (select max(id)-100 from trans) and (select max(id) from trans)
```

Comment: Erm ... you'd want the lower value as the first argument afet BETWEEN. I'm not sure that this would work though -- the optimiser is not necessarily going to realise that only about 100 rows of trans will be returned. Check the explain plan, though.

Answer (score 0):

The in does not seem to do anything have you tried removing it?

```
select a.id, b.field_one, c.field_two
from trans a, table_two b, table_three c
where a.id = b.id
and a.id = c.id
and a.id > (select max(id) from trans) - 100;
```

Comment: Doesn't the IN clause limit the results to only the most recent 100 inserts?

Comment: There is no reason to have the nested select in the in clause. All it did was ensure id was in the list of the ids greater than max(id) - 100. The same thing can be accomplished by directly comparing id to max(id) - 100.

Comment: I agree that it could be done easier. I just meant that it did actually do something, as opposed to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply filter the 100 record in the primary trans table itself instead of joing it again and again.

```
select a.id, b.field_one, c.field_two
from 
(select id from (select id, row_number() over(order by id desc) rn 
from trans) where rn <=100) a, 
table_two b, table_three c
where a.id = b.id
and a.id = c.id;
```